# how to change local git ssh-key?

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I was made a big mistake:override the local ssh-key.

Now, i generated a new ssh-key, and added it to the gitlab. 
But i'm still can't push code to the remote.

[this is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLNBD.png)

Please tell me how to switch the local ssh-key, thanks!

My operating system is OSX 10.11

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: @NilsWerner OS X 10.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ubuntu user, Please try this on terminal

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Add generated ssh key into `/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa` file

For more detail follow steps from below link

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Comment: is the keyName can be use other?  I generated a new key named `gitlab`,but it doesn't work.

Comment: i configed the `~/.ssh/config` file,and then it worked